# How can I handle File Uploads in a Microservice Environment?

Tags: php, microservices, file-handling, api-design

I am in the process of trying to make a decision on how, when and where to handle uploaded files from users. We are in a MicroService environment (PHP + Linux) for a new system to be deployed in the coming months. One key component is incoming files.

Currently as I see it There are 3 options (Maybe more that I am not yet aware of). They are as follows:

(1)

```
[CLIENT:file] -> 
    [GATEWAY API 
        FILE STORAGE HANDLER ->
        [a: MICROSERVICE-News]
        [b: MICROSERVICE-Authors]
        [c: MICROSERVICE-Logger]
    ] -> {response}`
```

In this scenario, the Gateway API is designed to handle talking directly with a storage service (S3, GCS), sets a filename, validates, etc. When a storage confirmation is received it then passes that filename and other data to other MicroServices as needed. I see this as being overall beneficial as the file is handled as soon as it's received and can fail without impacting anything else further down the line. It does however add complexity to the Gateway and can potentially slow things down quickly at peak times.

(2)

```
[CLIENT:file] ->
    [GATEWAY API
        [a: MICROSERVICE-Files]
        [b: MICROSERVICE-News]
        [c: MICROSERVICE-Authors]
        [d: MICROSERVICE-Logger]
    ] -> {response}
```

In this scenario, the file is received by the Gateway API and then has to pass it along to a files MicroService. This can be beneficial because it takes visibility away from the gateway and offers the flexibility of easily making changes inside of a service without impacting the gateway for instance. The major downside of this is that now a single file is being handled twice and will require computing additional resources.

(3)

```
[CLIENT:file] -> 
    [FILE API] -> {response} -> 
[CLIENT] -> 
    [GATEWAY API
        [a: MICROSERVICE-News]
        [b: MICROSERVICE-Authors]
        [c: MICROSERVICE-Logger]
    ] -> {response}
```

In this scenario, the Client is accountable for sending files to a separate service and using the response to send to the Gateway API. From a resource perspective this takes a huge load off of the Gateway API and allows it to only be concerned with data, never files. The major drawback of this is a Client can send faulty or malicious information to the Gateway API and would require additional validation to ensure the file is valid and exists. It also creates potential congruence problems in the future between services and clients.

I may be missing other options and would love to know if there are. Does anyone have experience with this and how did you solve or approach handling files in a MicroService architecture?

Comment: Is there any update? How solve this problem? I stuck to similar problem too.

Comment: @101110101100111111101101 There has been no solution to this challenge as I don't think there is any one way of doing this. We opted to use a flavor of option 3. By using a central authentication service and putting everything behind it, we can have the client process the file(s), return the location (bucket) information for the file(s) then execute the actual data request. By using the bucket information instead of the actual URI of the file(s), it's easier to check internally if the file exists and is valid before serving it up in the future.

Comment: Why not sending the file to the service that is going to use that,, and that service send the file to storage service to save in whatever cdn and return ref to the file?

Answer (score 1):

After a long research, I finally got a solution.

Scenario 3 is appropriate for you and you can skip the Gateway api as it says in @Tree

```
[CLIENT:file] -> 
    [FILE API] -> {response} -> 
[CLIENT] -> 
    [GATEWAY API
        [a: MICROSERVICE-News]
        [b: MICROSERVICE-Authors]
        [c: MICROSERVICE-Logger]
    ] -> {response}
```

**Example Scenario**

- user requests file upload

**Sample Request**

```
POST https://api.site.com/media/upload
```

**Sample Response**

```
{
    "location": "JPG-IMG-54f022ae8b3f4d979e925b4dp68e87"
}
```

- The user sends the request to share the news

**Sample Request**

```
POST https://api.site.com/v2/news

{
    "Text": "Foo and Bar",
    "location": "JPG-IMG-54f022ae8b3f4d979e925b4dp68e87"
}
```

- Uploaded files are controlled by api gateway

**Sample Request**

```
Get https://api.site.com/v2/JPG-IMG-54f022ae8b3f4d979e925b4dp68e87
```

- After verification, each microservice performs its own task

Comment: In my case I'm building an API-based system (for third party can use) using microservices, and user who use Terminal to use my system will have to send multiple requests to perform 1 task

Comment: combine with api gateway :)

Answer (score 1):

I think to those architectural questions there is no one-fits-all solution, it always depends on your context and quality goals.

If you prefer the encapsulation over performance, then go with solution (2). You might want to consider using a client-based service discovery mechanism for the file service instead of a full-blown API-Gateway to reduce the load on the gateway.

If you prefer performance and the client is under your control, then you can go with solution (3).

I'd avoid solution (1), though. Microservices have a principle "keep the smarts in the endpoints", meaning to avoid putting logic into infrastructure components like API-Gateways.

Answer (score 0):

```
[CLIENT:file] -> 
    [FILE API]
     -> {response}
     -> 
        [a: MICROSERVICE-News]
        [b: MICROSERVICE-Authors]
        [c: MICROSERVICE-Logger]
    ] -> {publish}
```

You can skip Gateway api in this example.

You File api verifies the file upload, and the data content. After it is succesfull, you make a response to a client that the upload was succesfull.

Later you process the upload in your microservices, and you use a sort of publisher to notify the client if for this data adds new actions in your other services.

In case your client depends on the processing of data, you have then 2 steps. First step is file upload response, that tells you that file was succesfully uploaded and verified.

Here you can react to this information by changing the gui, or still wait for the publisher information.
Publisher will send the imlpementation of the file information with either success or error, so you can finish your steps with your client